# Remove post if exist by title

Tags: wp-delete-post

> I want to remove a post from PHP by title.

I have a code for publish or update if the post exist by title, but I don't know how to insert the **wp_delete_post() function**.

This is my actual code for publish or update if the post exist by title:

```
<?php
// require wp-load.php to use built-in WordPress functions
require_once("/var/www/mysite.com/wp-load.php");

//Title
    $TítleProduct = ("Title Product 1");
//Desc
    $Desc = ("Product descripction 1");

// Register Post Data

$post = array();
$post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$post['post_type']     = 'post'; // can be a CPT too
$post['post_title']    = "$TítleProduct";
$post['post_content']  = ($Desc);
$post['post_author']   = 1;

    function wp_exist_post_by_title($title)
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $return_id = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "' && post_type = 'post' ", 'ARRAY_N');
        if (empty($return_id)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $return_id;
        }
    }

    $id = wp_exist_post_by_title($post['post_title']);

    if($id !== false)
    {
        $post['ID'] = $id["0"];
        $post_id = wp_update_post( $post );
    } else {
        $post['post_date']     = $my_post['post_date'];
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );
    }

/*******************************************************
** SIMPLE ERROR CHECKING
*******************************************************/

$finaltext = '';

if($post_id){

$finaltext .= 'Se ha creado/actualizado correctamente el post '.$post['ID'].'.<br>';

} else{

$finaltext .= 'Something went wrong and I didn\'t insert a new post.<br>';

}

echo $finaltext;
?>
```

I tried replacing **wp_update_post** for **wp_delete_post** and combinating with the **wp_delete_post function** but I don't know how combine it exacly, here is the wp_delete_post function code example:

```
function wp_delete_post( $postid = 0, $force_delete = false ) {
    global $wpdb;
 
    $post = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $postid ) );
 
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return $post;
    }
 
    $post = get_post( $post );
 
    if ( ! $force_delete && ( 'post' === $post->post_type || 'page' === $post->post_type ) && 'trash' !== get_post_status( $postid ) && EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS ) {
        return wp_trash_post( $postid );
    }
 
    if ( 'attachment' === $post->post_type ) {
        return wp_delete_attachment( $postid, $force_delete );
    }
 
    /**
     * Filters whether a post deletion should take place.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     *
     * @param bool|null $delete       Whether to go forward with deletion.
     * @param WP_Post   $post         Post object.
     * @param bool      $force_delete Whether to bypass the Trash.
     */
    $check = apply_filters( 'pre_delete_post', null, $post, $force_delete );
    if ( null !== $check ) {
        return $check;
    }
 
    /**
     * Fires before a post is deleted, at the start of wp_delete_post().
     *
     * @since 3.2.0
     * @since 5.5.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
     *
     * @see wp_delete_post()
     *
     * @param int     $postid Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post   Post object.
     */
    do_action( 'before_delete_post', $postid, $post );
 
    delete_post_meta( $postid, '_wp_trash_meta_status' );
    delete_post_meta( $postid, '_wp_trash_meta_time' );
 
    wp_delete_object_term_relationships( $postid, get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type ) );
 
    $parent_data  = array( 'post_parent' => $post->post_parent );
    $parent_where = array( 'post_parent' => $postid );
 
    if ( is_post_type_hierarchical( $post->post_type ) ) {
        // Point children of this page to its parent, also clean the cache of affected children.
        $children_query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = %d AND post_type = %s", $postid, $post->post_type );
        $children       = $wpdb->get_results( $children_query );
        if ( $children ) {
            $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $parent_data, $parent_where + array( 'post_type' => $post->post_type ) );
        }
    }
 
    // Do raw query. wp_get_post_revisions() is filtered.
    $revision_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = %d AND post_type = 'revision'", $postid ) );
    // Use wp_delete_post (via wp_delete_post_revision) again. Ensures any meta/misplaced data gets cleaned up.
    foreach ( $revision_ids as $revision_id ) {
        wp_delete_post_revision( $revision_id );
    }
 
    // Point all attachments to this post up one level.
    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $parent_data, $parent_where + array( 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) );
 
    wp_defer_comment_counting( true );
 
    $comment_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT comment_ID FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE comment_post_ID = %d", $postid ) );
    foreach ( $comment_ids as $comment_id ) {
        wp_delete_comment( $comment_id, true );
    }
 
    wp_defer_comment_counting( false );
 
    $post_meta_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT meta_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = %d ", $postid ) );
    foreach ( $post_meta_ids as $mid ) {
        delete_metadata_by_mid( 'post', $mid );
    }
 
    /**
     * Fires immediately before a post is deleted from the database.
     *
     * @since 1.2.0
     * @since 5.5.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
     *
     * @param int     $postid Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post   Post object.
     */
    do_action( 'delete_post', $postid, $post );
 
    $result = $wpdb->delete( $wpdb->posts, array( 'ID' => $postid ) );
    if ( ! $result ) {
        return false;
    }
 
    /**
     * Fires immediately after a post is deleted from the database.
     *
     * @since 2.2.0
     * @since 5.5.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
     *
     * @param int     $postid Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post   Post object.
     */
    do_action( 'deleted_post', $postid, $post );
 
    clean_post_cache( $post );
 
    if ( is_post_type_hierarchical( $post->post_type ) && $children ) {
        foreach ( $children as $child ) {
            clean_post_cache( $child );
        }
    }
 
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'publish_future_post', array( $postid ) );
 
    /**
     * Fires after a post is deleted, at the conclusion of wp_delete_post().
     *
     * @since 3.2.0
     * @since 5.5.0 Added the `$post` parameter.
     *
     * @see wp_delete_post()
     *
     * @param int     $postid Post ID.
     * @param WP_Post $post   Post object.
     */
    do_action( 'after_delete_post', $postid, $post );
 
    return $post;
}
```

Comment: When you want to delete the post? While it's being created/modified or search for posts with containing title and delete them? In any case, you will need the post ID in order to delete.

Comment: Search for posts by title and delete them (I get this from the URL and works fine), but I need now delete the post by title.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, the posts search field in posts screen should help. Just search for the term there.

Comment: I want to do it through an automation that I have created, for this reason I need to do it in php

Answer (score 0):

The `s` parameter of WP Query search posts within the title and content columns of the posts table. You can use that to shorten your code. Here is a sample bit to help you get started.

You can hook it in `wp_footer` to run only once (very bad idea to keep it there, but good for testing), or create a cron job to run it automatically on a selected interval.

```
function wpse388545_delete_selected_posts() {
    
    $get_posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => array('post'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => 'This is the search term',
    ));
    
    if ( !empty($get_posts) ) {
        foreach( $get_posts as $post ) {
            wp_delete_post($post->ID, true);
        }
    }
}
```